# What is this Font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I ran the below image through What the Font without any luck. Can someone help me identify what font this is, or a very close substitute? Note: The effect on the font may be the font or may be styling. I can replicate the styling if I can get the font correct.

[image: Font to Identify]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was finally able to speak to the graphic artist who created the text.

[The font is VTKS Desgaste](http://www.dafont.com/vtks-desgaste.font)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [The Dead Saloon](http://www.dafont.com/the-dead-saloon.font) but maybe shortened and with a curve to it.

[image]

Comment: It has similarities but, unless it's a modified version it's not that. Look at the Cap A's

Comment: As @danielhanly.com pointed out it isn't exact but it is a close match and I may be able to use this. Thank You for finding this.

Comment: It's in the same style, but wouldn't say it's close. But I guess that depends on one's own definition of 'close'

Comment: Hi, maybe you could try this http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to identify that font

Comment: Why are you telling me? Comment on the asker.

Comment: @Lukaydo See the first sentence of the question!